# Uploading and resizing images to S3

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on new website and uploading images feature. I also want to resize uploaded image to 3 different sizes : Large, Medium and Small.
I've tried to upload images directly to a bucket in S3,uploading is working but not able to resize image.

I've looked over the search results and I didn't found something clear about it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Explain `upload image to S3 but without success`. First resize locally files, than upload. S3 is not like normal HDD

Comment: I don't know how to upload it, the only think I know is to upload image using AWS UI to my currently bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is a cloud storage platform. So it would be better to process(resize) images locally before uploading them to S3. 
Alternatively if you are not restricted to AWS S3, you could use a very popular cloud service "[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)" to do the same without any hassle.

Comment: It is part of my Cloud Course and not my personal website, so I need to do it on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize images using [**Lambda**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) function on Amezon S3.

AWS **Lambda** is a compute service where you can upload your code to AWS Lambda and the service can run the code on your behalf using AWS infrastructure. After you upload your code and create what we call a Lambda function, AWS Lambda takes care of provisioning and managing the servers that you use to run the code. You can use AWS Lambda as follows:

- As an event-driven compute service where AWS Lambda runs your code in response to events, such as changes to data in an Amazon S3 bucket or an Amazon DynamoDB table.
- As a compute service to run your code in response to HTTP requests using Amazon API Gateway or API calls made using AWS SDKs.

I'll suggest you to keep two bucket first one will store original images and second one store resized images.And make sure you have installed AWS CLI so that you can install Lambda using.
You can take a look this [link](https://cloudonaut.io/serverless-image-resizing-at-any-scale/) to install Lambda and how can use this to resize images uploaded on AWS S3.

Comment: How do I work with Lambda in AWS ? is there any tutorial that I can see and implement ?

Comment: I created a project which aims to simplify the whole "resize images from s3 in lambda" process and abstract it into a simple configuration file. (https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-sharp-image) Once you've set it up and configured how you want to resize your images, all you have to do is upload images to an S3 bucket and it'll do the rest.